# Código extraño en wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

Estoy iniciando en wordpress y no tengo demasiados conociemientos en este tema.

Importé un archivo xml al wordpress pero al inspeccionar cada una de las vistas me aparecen shortcodes que no sé que son , creo que es algo relacionado con plugins que faltan pero no sé cuales son dejo una imagen que muestra ese error

Sabes como sulucionarlo?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: `et_pb_section` es un shortcode del builder divi

Comment: Sí estoy usando otro theme ahora , existe alguna forma de solucionarlo ? Usando ese shortcode en el nuevo theme capaz o simplemente borro ese shortcode? @aloMalbarez

Comment: según tengo entendido el builder se puede adquirir separado del theme, no se si hay una version free con toda la librería de módulos